# Какая связь GET-запроса и сессии

Tags: django, веб-программирование

Расскажите пожалуйста, какая связь может быть между GET-запросом и сессией?

Может ли GET-запрос передавать параметры, а URL не будет иметь добавочную информацию с содержанием `?` и именами со значениями?

Comment: Может, в пути запроса. Или в заголовках..

Comment: Мне всё ещё не совсем понятно, что вы хотите от запроса и сессии, есть пример?